# Proc Tabulate Percentage SAS

Tags: sas, proc

I have the following tabulation that I created using Proc tabulate:

[image]

You will notice that I have left my PCTN column empty because the code I am running (below) is giving me the wrong percentages

This is my code:

```
ods tagsets.excelxp file = 'G:\CPS\myworknew.xml'
style = analysis;
proc tabulate data = final;
Class Year P_Occupation Full_Part_Time_Status Self_Emp_Inc Self_Emp_Uninc Self_Emp Multi_Job;
table year, P_Occupation P_Occupation*Self_Emp_Inc*(N pctn<P_Occupation>);           
run;
ods tagsets.excelxp close;
```

How I actually want the percentages to be calculated is as the following:
For example for Architecture and enginneering occupations for self_emp_inc Type A I want: (16083/16595)*100. In another words I want the P_Occupation total (Cell B7 = 16595) as the denominator. Same for when Type = B (512/16595)*100. 
And the next Pctn value for Architecture and engineering for Type A to be (15479/15869)*100, for Type B (390/15869)*100. 
I then want the same thing for the Arts, Design, Entertaiment... column but the denominator will come from the Arts,Design, Entertainment column instead of Architecutre and Engineering: So for example for Type A of it would be: (14925/15896)*100 and for Type B it would be (971/15896)*100.

How can I accomplish this task? I keep typing the wrong value for Pctn

Here is portion of the dataset:

[image]

Comment: You'll get better answers if you include some sample data.  Look at the example I made for your other question - find a dataset, like `sashelp.cars` or `sashelp.class` - that can show the problem you're having, or otherwise include some example data in datalines.

Comment: hi, I added a portion of the dataset

Comment: Please don't use pictures; include the data as text, preferably as datalines in a data step.

Comment: Do you just want me to include a portion of the dataset since the dataset has millions of observations.

Comment: You should include enough data - real or made up - to show the issue you are having and to be able to create a solution. You do not have to use any of your real data - it is often easier to just use one of the SASHELP datasets which all users will have (like Cars or Class).

Comment: Year P_Occupation self_Emp_in
2015 Food prepration and serving related occupations A
2015 Education, Training, and Library Occupations A
2015 Life, Physical, and Social Science Occupations A
2015 Business & Financial Operations Occupations A
2015 Healthcare Practitioners and Technical Occupations A
2015 Business & Financial Operations Occupations A
2015 Food prepration and serving related occupations A
2015 Construction and Extraction Occupations A
2015 Food prepration and serving related occupations A
2015 Community and Social Service Occupations A

Comment: @user2916331 Data in comments or pictures is not usable for coding.